# How to parse datetime returned in json from webapi to print at front end in yyyy/mm/dd format using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, date, datetime

```
[
    {"AIRLINE":"Air India","FLIGHT_NO_":"AI-202","DATE":"2019-11-23T00:00:00","DEPARTURE":"08:15:00","ARRIVAL":"11:45:00","FROM":"BOM","TO":"KOL","PRICE":2800.0000},
    {"AIRLINE":"Vistara","FLIGHT_NO_":"VS-105","DATE":"2019-11-23T00:00:00","DEPARTURE":"10:00:00","ARRIVAL":"12:30:00","FROM":"BOM","TO":"KOL","PRICE":3100.0000},
    {"AIRLINE":"Jet Airways","FLIGHT_NO_":"JA-303","DATE":"2019-11-23T00:00:00","DEPARTURE":"10:20:00","ARRIVAL":"22:15:00","FROM":"BOM","TO":"KOL","PRICE":4000.0000}
]
```

I have above json and i am doing this in my script.

```
                             var rows = "<tr>" +
                                 "<td id='AIRLINE'>" + item.AIRLINE + "</td>" +
                                 "<td id='FLIGHT'>" + item.FLIGHT_NO_ + "</td>" +
                                 "<td id='DATE'>" + Date(item.DATE) + "</td>" +
                                 "<td id='DEPARTURE'>" + item.DEPARTURE + "</td>" +
                                 "<td id='ARRIVAL'>" + item.ARRIVAL +
                                 "<td id='FROM'>" + item.FROM +
                                 "<td id='TO'>" + item.TO +
                                 "<td id='PRICE'>" + item.PRICE +
                                 "</td>" +
                                 "</tr>";
                            $('#tblBody').append(rows);
```

but it is returning current system datetime.

Vistara VS-105  **Tue Nov 19 2019 12:42:06 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)** 10:00:00    12:30:00    BOM KOL 3100
Jet Airways JA-303  **Tue Nov 19 2019 12:42:06 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)** 10:20:00    22:15:00    BOM KOL 4000

Comment: ```Date(item.dates)``` Why?

Comment: Date(item.DATE)

Comment: Currently i am doing this to format the date in format `Date(item.DATE, "dd/mm/yyy")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function Date() returns the current system date. You just need to change `Date()` to `new Date()` to create a new instance of date object. Check the difference in the snippet below:

```js
document.write (Date("2019-11-23T00:00:00") + "<br>");
document.write (new Date("2019-11-23T00:00:00"));
```